# Compiling Ajax with append jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to append a span, which contains PHP code, i know there should be a way to call the script by AJAX.

But i'm beginner in jQuery so i need someone helps to get resolved the issue.

Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("#grid").append("<?php the_sub_field('image');?>");
  });
});
```

Comment: To begin with you should never, ever, mix JavaScript and PHP. Now you're just appending a string to the div, nothing's suppose to happen.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to append.  Is the value to be appended known at the time the page is loaded?  If so, then the current syntax is correct in that you'd just emit that value from PHP code into the JavaScript code.  If not, how is the value going to be calculated?  Can it be calculated client-side, or does it need to be calculated server-side?  If server-side then you would need to have a server-side handler (page) of some kind to perform the calculation and return the result.  Then you'd use `.ajax()` or some equivalent to get the value.

Comment: You can't do that. PHP is ran on the server and translated to html. Instead what you want is to append an html response from your server I think

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to execute that PHP code there. PHP is run on the server, which is then sent to the browser. JavaScript is on the browser and can't interpret PHP. So, you need to send an AJAX call to the server.

JavaScript

`$.ajax({
    url: 'desintation.php',
    success: function( response ){ console.log( response ); }
});`

PHP: desination.php

`the_sub_field('image');`

Answer (score 0):

While I strongly recommend you not do this, you could create a PHP script which contains your Javascript, and then outputs the right content-type header:

```
<?php
// jsfile.php
header('Content-type: text/javascript');
?>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("#grid").append("<?php the_sub_field('image');?>");
  });
});
```

And then link to that file with a script tag:

```
<script src='/path/to/jsfile.php'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're just appending a string to the div, the result will look like this:

```
<div id="grid"><!--?php the_sub_field('image');?--></div>
```

I just [tried it out](http://jsfiddle.net/4A34b/) myself and this is the result when you inspect the html after clicking the button. I guess it's even commented out just for the sake of someone trying to do something very suspicious.

Why? JavaScript is client-side and PHP is server-side, the PHP code isn't run unless it's told to run on the server.

AJAX is when you communicate with the server from the client and you usually get some kind of a response back from the server. You can tell the server that you want some data, images, etc, and then it's sent to the client which can handle the data however it likes.

Take a look at how actual [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is performed.

And by the way, if you think you can mix JavaScript and PHP with no problems, you're gonna have a bad time.